# Unable to Inject IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

Hello I am building a AspNetCore 2 WebApi application using angular 4 and JWT
the broad definition of my issue is that I am unable to access `HttpContext.User` outside of my controllers.

I am aware that this is by design and that .net gives us `IHttpContextAccessor` for this very reason. I am also aware that in R2 `IHttpContextAccessor` is no longer registered by default and that it should be registered as a singleton. here is a bit of my startup.cs

```cs
 1.) services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
 2.) services.AddSignalR();
 3.) services.AddTransient<ClaimsPrincipal>(s => s.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
 4.) services.AddTransient<UserResolverService>();
```

As you can see I have tried a few things,
for one i obviously am just adding an `IHttpContextAccessor` which I attempt to inject like this (which breaks, HttpContext is null)

```cs
private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _caller;
public ChatHub(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
   _caller = accessor.HttpContext.User;
}
```

I have attempted putting this in a service and then injecting the service like this

```cs
private string _userName;
public ChatHub(UserResolverService userService)
{
   _user = userService.GetUser();
}
```

here is the service I mention (and also register as yo u can see above)

```cs
public class UserResolverService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

    public UserResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }

    public string GetUser()
    {
        return _context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

this was just something I found here on stack overflow, seems to do nothing

```cs
services.AddTransient<ClaimsPrincipal>(s => 
s.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
```

Im a little new to posting and I dont want to go off topic but in case it helps anyone really all I am trying to do is map users to connections in signalR, I have the chatSample from the github (https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/tree/dev/samples/ChatSample)
working completely and perfectly in my app, aside from the fact that

```cs
Context.User.Identity.Name
```

is null. and by context I am referring to

```cs
HubCallerContext Hub.Context
```

however I dont imagine that the fact this is signalR is important. I should just be able to inject HttpContext and get the user info I need that way right?
what am I missing? day 2 on this issue going nuts

Comment: If you are not accessing `HttpContext.User` within the context of a request then `HttpContext` will be null.

Comment: So In this instance the request is over WebSockets. is that a problem?

Comment: Do you have access to a `HubConnectionContext`? If so, it looks like there is an extension method which can provide access to the context. See [HttpConnectionContextExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/595f783857598c56056305d627b969b856367454/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Http/HttpConnectionContextExtensions.cs)

Comment: Yeah so i guess really my issue is that HubConnectionContext.User.Identity isn't hydrated. which is completely separate from the  question i asked and therefore i need to ask a new one. if you post an answer ill accept it and make a new one

Comment: Feel free to edit this question or delete and create anew if you would prefer.